# Blank page when PHP encounters errors

Tags: php

While I was creating a PHP page, it is always irritating to hit into a blank page when testing (should be a php error somewhere). How do I get it to spill whatever errors in PHP that may have occurred ?

The source code links:

- http://ahb.me/15aR (addbookmarks.php)
- http://ahb.me/15aU (managebookmarks.php)

The problem I am facing is that after adding session in both php files to handle and highlight empty fields in HTML forms, the entire addbookmarks.php just went blank when it is being run and tested.

Sorry for the long lines of codes. The suggestions to use codes to enable showing of error did not do anything at all. The page is still blank.

Comment: My dev env is:
error_append_string - no value - no value,error_log - no value - no value,error_prepend_string - no value - no value,error_reporting - 22527 - 22527

Answer (score 3):

put this at the beginning of the php script
`error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');`
Use this only in development. When you go to production you should remove them and log your errors to a file

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation:

```
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Or, as goreSplatter says, this should do it:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1)
```

Try putting that at the top of your scripts. These commands will set PHP to show all errors from that script during runtime.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the manual page with details on error reporting](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php)

---

EDIT : on your *addbookmark.php*, you don't have `error_reporting` etc...
Putting it in one file won't set it for the others.

Anyway, if you have access to your php.ini, you can set it for every page...

Comment: Generally a good idea to be a bit more descriptive. Simply specifying `this` is obscure.

Comment: @Russell Dias - I edited it. Anyway, I usually put a link to the manual every time I answer this way. You're the first that seems to be disturb. People watch status bar before click and I don't use a short url.

Comment: @thotheolh : I edited my answer for your _addbookmark.php_ file

Comment: @Chouchenos The status bar hardly gives information about the article to which you are linking to.

Comment: @Russell Dias : Seriously _php.net_ / _manual_ / _function error reporting_ no information to the article in the url in the status bar? You must be kidding right?

Comment: @Chouchenos Your edit is perfect. I was merely referring to your answer pre edit :)

Comment: @Russell Dias : I did too... The url of the page is http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php . When you mouseover it, it's shown on the status bar. And seriously, the url is pretty understandable of what you'll see if you click it. I edited it to end the _arguing_ which will lead to nothing, I'll do as I always do in the future pleasing you or not ;)

Comment: @Chouchenos It's not about pleasing an individual, but rather the community. Would you prefer descriptive or non-descriptive links? This site is a treasure trove of information, partly due to the fact that it is very accessible and the answers are very well formatted. Descriptive links makes it easier for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you redirect to other page or your request page show some data and php program have bug and cant complete data...
trace your program with print or exit() or var_dump()

also you can use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

of course best way is use error handler